# How do we get Knowledge article Rating by SOAP api

Tags: soql, api, quip

In Knowledge Article, we getting all description about knowledge article by using "KnowledgeArticleVersion" but this API is not return rating of the article also likes and viewing the score.

If anybody knows please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is stored under different objects so you will have to get it from them.

Link to the API docs -

[KnowledgeArticleVoteStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm) - Rating score

[KnowledgeArticleViewStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleviewstat.htm) - Viewing score

Comment: Sure, But when I use "KnowledgeArticleVersion" I am getting article id which I have created inside knowledge object something like this "ka06F00000084hEQAQ". after that I am calling this "KnowledgeArticleVoteState" inside response we have parantId but parent id is not matched with KnowledgeArtcileVersion records's Id.

so how could I filter by id and parent id bases for getting the score from Salesforce?

Comment: You should pass the KnowledgeArticle Id, not the KnowledgeArtcileVersion record Id.

Comment: I am working with the KnowledgeArtcileVersion object. Is that both same KnowledgeArtcileVersion and KnowledgeArticle?

Comment: Unlike KnowledgeArticleVersion, the ID of a KnowledgeArticle record is identical irrespective of the article's version (status). For more information on articles and article types, see “Work with Articles and Translations” and “Knowledge Article Types” in the Salesforce online help.

Please check the SOAP api docs once.

Comment: Sure,  I just want to get the score and rating of the specific article. Is that any simple method you know? or any kind of API for that purpose? Can u please help me out this.